# How to get Calendar Column names from DataBase in android 2.1..?

Tags: android

here is my code.. which works fine in android 1.6.. but throws IllegalArguementException in 2.1 devices.

```
Uri calendars = Uri.parse("content://com.android.calendar/calendars");
        Cursor managedCursor =   managedQuery(calendars, null,null, null, null);


    if (managedCursor.moveToFirst()) 
    {   int i = managedCursor.getColumnCount();
    for (int j = 0; j < managedCursor.getColumnCount(); j++) {

        Log.d("#$$$$$$$$############","##"+managedCursor.getColumnName(j));

    }
        Log.d("################@@@@@@@@",String.valueOf(i));

        int nameColumn = managedCursor.getColumnIndex("name");  
        int idColumn = managedCursor.getColumnIndex("_id"); 
        do 
        {    
            calName = managedCursor.getString(1);    
            calId = managedCursor.getString(0); 
            } while (managedCursor.moveToNext());
    }
    ContentValues event = new ContentValues();
    event.put("calendar_id", calId);
    event.put("title", "Event Title");
    event.put("description", "Event Desc");
    event.put("eventLocation", "Event Location");

    event.put("hasAlarm", 1); 
     Uri eventsUri = Uri.parse("content://com.android.calendar/calendars");  
     Uri url = getContentResolver().insert(eventsUri, event);
```

and the logCat has this...

```
06-21 15:53:42.112: DEBUG/#$$$$$$$$############(4605): ##_id
06-21 15:53:42.112: DEBUG/#$$$$$$$$############(4605): ##_sync_account
06-21 15:53:42.112: DEBUG/#$$$$$$$$############(4605): ##_sync_account_type
06-21 15:53:42.112: DEBUG/#$$$$$$$$############(4605): ##_sync_id
06-21 15:53:42.112: DEBUG/#$$$$$$$$############(4605): ##_sync_version
06-21 15:53:42.112: DEBUG/#$$$$$$$$############(4605): ##_sync_time
06-21 15:53:42.112: DEBUG/#$$$$$$$$############(4605): ##_sync_local_id
06-21 15:53:42.112: DEBUG/#$$$$$$$$############(4605): ##_sync_dirty
06-21 15:53:42.112: DEBUG/#$$$$$$$$############(4605): ##_sync_mark
06-21 15:53:42.112: DEBUG/#$$$$$$$$############(4605): ##url
06-21 15:53:42.112: DEBUG/#$$$$$$$$############(4605): ##name
06-21 15:53:42.112: DEBUG/#$$$$$$$$############(4605): ##displayName
06-21 15:53:42.112: DEBUG/#$$$$$$$$############(4605): ##hidden
06-21 15:53:42.112: DEBUG/#$$$$$$$$############(4605): ##color
06-21 15:53:42.112: DEBUG/#$$$$$$$$############(4605): ##access_level
06-21 15:53:42.112: DEBUG/#$$$$$$$$############(4605): ##selected
06-21 15:53:42.112: DEBUG/#$$$$$$$$############(4605): ##sync_events
06-21 15:53:42.112: DEBUG/#$$$$$$$$############(4605): ##location
06-21 15:53:42.112: DEBUG/#$$$$$$$$############(4605): ##timezone
06-21 15:53:42.112: DEBUG/#$$$$$$$$############(4605): ##ownerAccount
06-21 15:53:42.112: DEBUG/#$$$$$$$$############(4605): ##organizerCanRespond
06-21 15:53:42.122: DEBUG/################@@@@@@@@(4605): 21
06-21 15:53:42.132: ERROR/DatabaseUtils(1717): Writing exception to parcel
06-21 15:53:42.132: ERROR/DatabaseUtils(1717): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: column 'calendar_id' is invalid
06-21 15:53:42.132: ERROR/DatabaseUtils(1717):     at android.database.DatabaseUtils$InsertHelper.getColumnIndex(DatabaseUtils.java:907)
06-21 15:53:42.132: ERROR/DatabaseUtils(1717):     at android.database.DatabaseUtils$InsertHelper.insertInternal(DatabaseUtils.java:883)
06-21 15:53:42.132: ERROR/DatabaseUtils(1717):     at android.database.DatabaseUtils$InsertHelper.insert(DatabaseUtils.java:1011)
06-21 15:53:42.132: ERROR/DatabaseUtils(1717):     at com.android.providers.calendar.CalendarDatabaseHelper.calendarsInsert(CalendarDatabaseHelper.java:88)
06-21 15:53:42.132: ERROR/DatabaseUtils(1717):     at com.android.providers.calendar.CalendarProvider2.insertInTransaction(CalendarProvider2.java:1659)
06-21 15:53:42.132: ERROR/DatabaseUtils(1717):     at com.android.providers.calendar.SQLiteContentProvider.insert(SQLiteContentProvider.java:90)
06-21 15:53:42.132: ERROR/DatabaseUtils(1717):     at android.content.ContentProvider$Transport.insert(ContentProvider.java:174)
06-21 15:53:42.132: ERROR/DatabaseUtils(1717):     at android.content.ContentProviderNative.onTransact(ContentProviderNative.java:146)
06-21 15:53:42.132: ERROR/DatabaseUtils(1717):     at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:288)
06-21 15:53:42.132: ERROR/DatabaseUtils(1717):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
06-21 15:53:42.142: WARN/dalvikvm(4605): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40020ac0)
06-21 15:53:42.142: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4605): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-21 15:53:42.142: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4605): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.aquilonis.xblockr.callHandller/com.android.pro.utility.AppointmentPro}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: column 'calendar_id' is invalid
06-21 15:53:42.142: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4605):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)
06-21 15:53:42.142: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4605):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
06-21 15:53:42.142: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4605):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
06-21 15:53:42.142: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4605):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
06-21 15:53:42.142: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4605):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-21 15:53:42.142: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4605):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
06-21 15:53:42.142: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4605):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
06-21 15:53:42.142: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4605):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-21 15:53:42.142: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4605):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
06-21 15:53:42.142: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4605):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)
06-21 15:53:42.142: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4605):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
06-21 15:53:42.142: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4605):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-21 15:53:42.142: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4605): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: column 'calendar_id' is invalid
06-21 15:53:42.142: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4605):     at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:144)
06-21 15:53:42.142: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4605):     at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:114)
06-21 15:53:42.142: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4605):     at android.content.ContentProviderProxy.insert(ContentProviderNative.java:408)
06-21 15:53:42.142: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4605):     at android.content.ContentResolver.insert(ContentResolver.java:587)
06-21 15:53:42.142: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4605):     at com.android.pro.utility.AppointmentPro.onCreate(AppointmentPro.java:54)
06-21 15:53:42.142: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4605):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
06-21 15:53:42.142: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4605):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
06-21 15:53:42.142: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4605):     ... 11 more
06-21 15:53:42.152: WARN/ActivityManager(1374):   Force finishing activity com.aquilonis.xblockr.callHandller/com.android.pro.utility.AppointmentPro
06-21 15:53:42.152: WARN/ActivityManager(1374):   Force finishing activity com.aquilonis.xblockr.callHandller/com.android.pro.ui.ProHomeScreen
```

Is there anyone who can help me out... I'm struggling from past 3 days..

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following code for android2.1

```
Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(Uri.parse("content://calendar/calendars"),
                        new String[] { "_id", "displayName" }, "selected=1", null, null);
        if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
             String[] calNames = new String[cursor.getCount()];
             int[] calIds = new int[cursor.getCount()];
             for (int i = 0; i < calNames.length; i++) {
                  // retrieve the calendar names and ids
                  // at this stage you can print out the display names to get an idea of what calendars the user has
                  calIds[i] = cursor.getInt(0);
                  calNames[i] = cursor.getString(1);
                  cursor.moveToNext();
              }
              cursor.close();
              if (calIds.length > 0) {
                   // we're safe here to do any further work
              }


     // grab calendar id from above
        int cal_id = calIds[0];

        // set the content value
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();

        // make sure you add it to the right calendar
        cv.put("calendar_id", cal_id);

        // set the title of the event
        cv.put("title", "jwei's birthday");

        // set the description of the event
        cv.put("description", "Time to celebrate jwei's birthday.");

        // set the event's physical location
        cv.put("eventLocation", "Palo Alto, CA");

        // set the start and end time
        // note: you're going to need to convert the desired date into milliseconds
        cv.put("dtstart", System.currentTimeMillis());
        cv.put("dtend", System.currentTimeMillis() + DateUtils.DAY_IN_MILLIS);

        // let the calendar know whether this event goes on all day or not
        // true = 1, false = 0
        cv.put("allDay", 1);

        // let the calendar know whether an alarm should go off for this event
        cv.put("hasAlarm", 1);

        // once desired fields are set, insert it into the table
        getContentResolver().insert(Uri.parse("content://calendar/events"), cv);
        }
```

Comment: 06-21 16:23:43.832: INFO/ActivityManager(1374): Starting activity: Intent { cmp=com.aquilonis.xblockr.callHandller/com.android.pro.utility.AppointmentPro }
06-21 16:23:43.852: ERROR/ActivityThread(5398): Failed to find provider info for calendar
06-21 16:23:43.872: WARN/InputManagerService(1374): Window already focused, ignoring focus gain of: com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub$Proxy@45014e68
.. Activity was not started.. above thing appeared in LogCat.. would u mind sharing some more of your code..

Comment: have a look on http://thinkandroid.wordpress.com/2010/06/20/sync-ing-with-androids-calendar/

Answer (score 0):

because on line event.put("calendar_id", calId); callId should be int

i have these code for that

```
private void addToCalendar(Context ctx, final String title, final long dtstart, final long dtend) {
    final ContentResolver cr = ctx.getContentResolver();
    Cursor cursor ;
    if (Integer.parseInt(Build.VERSION.SDK) == 8 )
        cursor = cr.query(Uri.parse("content://com.android.calendar/calendars"), new String[]{ "_id", "displayname" }, null, null, null);
    else
        cursor = cr.query(Uri.parse("content://calendar/calendars"), new String[]{ "_id", "displayname" }, null, null, null);
    if ( cursor.moveToFirst() ) {
        final String[] calNames = new String[cursor.getCount()];
        final int[] calIds = new int[cursor.getCount()];
        for (int i = 0; i < calNames.length; i++) {
            calIds[i] = cursor.getInt(0);
            calNames[i] = cursor.getString(1);
            cursor.moveToNext();
        }

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(ctx);
        builder.setSingleChoiceItems(calNames, -1, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
                cv.put("calendar_id", calIds[which]);
                cv.put("title", title);
                cv.put("dtstart", dtstart );
                cv.put("hasAlarm", 1);
                cv.put("dtend", dtstart);
```

Comment: another thing is tat look at the values it prints in logCat which r returned from Database...? they look totally diff.. i don't understand wat r those.. i'm a fresher still

Answer (score 0):

instead of "displayName" use "calendar_displayName"

Now check and let us know..

happy coding!